# why am I being denied my rights in sudo?

Tags: permissions, themes, sudo

why am I being denid my rights to delete directories even I created in sudo now I cannot rid myself of it -- yes it is empty

did this to insure I have sudo in the accounts:

```
userz@bw:~$ sudo adduser userx sudo
[sudo] password for userz: 
The user `userx' is already a member of `sudo'.
userz@bw:~$ sudo adduser userz sudo
The user `userz' is already a member of `sudo'.
userz@bw:~$ cd /usr/local/share
```

so then I tried to delete the directory:

```
userz@bw:/usr/local/share$ rmdir themes
rmdir: failed to remove ‘themes’: Permission denied
```

checked to be sure it is empty:

```
userz@bw:/usr/local/share$ cd themes
userz@bw:/usr/local/share/themes$ ls
userz@bw:/usr/local/share/themes$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct  2 14:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Oct  2 14:20 ..
userz@bw:/usr/local/share/themes$
```

if I am in sudo then why it not let me be super user dude to do what I will?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable root login?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login)

Comment: It's not a duplicate the OP does not want to enable root; They want to know why **sudo** isn't working. Have you set a password for your main user account.  Sudo doesn't work if you have a blank password.  If not see [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](http://askubuntu.com/q/24006/107450).  If you have a password then edit the question to give us the output of `id` and then use instructions to reset the password to log in to a recovery shell don't change your password but provide the output of `cat /etc/sudoers`

Comment: @WarrenHill There is no point in doing all this. OP's sudo is working just fine, as the `sudo adduser` in the first line of his post shows.

Answer (score 3):

Being a member of the sudo group just means that you are allowed to sudo into the root role. To actually perform an action as root, specify it as an argument to the sudo command:

```
sudo rmdir themes
```

The `sudo` command will elevate you to `root` and then execute `rmdir themes`.

Answer (score 2):

Beeing a member of the group `sudo` just allows an user to use the program `sudo` to get superuser privileges. But you still have to actually use `sudo` to get superuser privileges, for example

```
userz@bw:/usr/local/share$ sudo rmdir themes
```

Comment: Wow Florian, we wrote almost **literally** the same at the same time! :-)

Comment: @zwets and made me write another answer that is not in the sightless the same to you both :P

Comment: therefore every time I need to use su right I have to type sudo first then the command ? then what is the sudo [enter] the put password in then [enter] again good for? and thanks

Comment: @user198193 what? Please check my answer.

Comment: @user198193 the only thing that is good for is to see its usage instructions; that's all you get when you do `sudo [enter]`. Or do you get something different?

Answer (score 2):

Of course it will not allow you to remove the directory because **you are not root**!

```
$ whoami
braiam
$ sudo whoami
[sudo] password for braiam: 
root
$
```

Before doing any operand that requires sudo privileges you should use `sudo`, not just being part of the sudo group.

Here is how you delete a directory with `sudo`:

```
$ ls -al somedir/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root   4096 oct  2 18:02 .
```

^ Here I have a directory owned by root.

```
$ sudo rmdir -v somedir
rmdir: removing directory, ‘somedir’
```

Here I'm telling to **super user** to **do** `rmdir` (remove directory) with `-v` (verbose) parameters called `somedir`.

```
$ ls -l somedir/
ls: cannot access somedir/: No such file or directory
```

Now, `somedir` do not exist anymore, it went KAPUT!