# Need to copy firmware files at /usr/lib to /lib using terminal

Tags: wireless, command-line, xubuntu, root, firmware

I have a Cubox-i4Pro and I'm running Xubuntu on it. In order to get Wi-Fi working I have to copy the firmware folder "brcm" from /usr/lib/firmware/brcm and make the folder /lib/firmware/brcm.  Refer to the article here.

http://www.solid-run.com/community/topic1269.html

After that, I have to do other stuff.  If I may get some help so that I can use Wi-Fi on my Cubox-iPro that would be great.  I have to do all this as root so I have to do it all from the terminal. Thanks. :)

P.S. I already know how to get to root.  (In the terminal)  Is there a way to log in as root so that I can do these things using the Dekstop?  There is no root login on the login screen. xD  All comments are appreciated.

EDIT:  I also need help with the rest of the steps.  This step has been solved.

Comment: Regarding your second question: First: Read http://askubuntu.com/questions/6676/why-is-there-no-option-to-login-as-root/6680#6680. Then read http://askubuntu.com/questions/70534/difference-between-su-sudo-s-sudo-i and then pick one of `sudo -i` and `sudo su -` to get a root shell. Then, (entirely your responsibility if bad things happen): http://askubuntu.com/questions/369012/how-to-run-a-complete-gui-as-root/369013#369013

Comment: This question have ~8 years old and related to Xubuntu 14.04. If you need help with the other steps please create a new updated question.

Comment: Note that in current Ubuntu distributions, /lib is just a link to /usr/lib (and /bin to /usr/bin and /sbin to /usr/sbin) -- such copies no longer meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

To copy the `firmware` folder to `/lib`:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/firmware /lib -R
```

To make a symbolic link (or softlink/symlink) to `/usr/lib/modules/3.10.30-20-ARCH` in  `/lib/modules`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/modules/3.10.30-20-ARCH /lib/modules/3.10.30-20-ARCH
```

Be careful, though. This looks like a path that depends on the kernel version. The `modules` folder may not even exist.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 on a Xubuntu Desktop Environment.

Comment: @NathanMorris updated.

Comment: Yeah.  This is the ARCH Linux Kernel.  It's a G'Zipped Kernel and runs on an ARM processor.  It's a cute little PC though. 2 GBs RAM and a quad core each at 1.0 GHz.

Comment: Error, the directory /lib/modules doesn't exist. :\  Now what?  And the article is found here...  http://www.solid-run.com/community/topic1269.html  I would recommend reading it so that you can further understand what I'm going through.  Sorry to bug so much.  I just really want to get Wi-Fi working before I go on vacation so that I can use the Wi-Fi at the hotel.

Comment: @NathanMorris using another distro's kernel is a bit beyond my expertise, so unaccept my answer, then edit and update your question to show what you have already done (all steps) (also change the title to state the main problem). I'll update my answer if I can figure it out, but it's best to leave the question open so that others will look into it.

Comment: Okay.  I'm also contacting the creators of the image to see if they can find any information about it.  Thanks for all your help.  I'm one more step forward! :D