# Desktop environment only displays the background if logged in as root

Tags: command-line, 16.04

After I login as root user, nothing is displayed except the background. 
Doing so from another user accounts works correctly. What could the issue be?

Comment: You should not be logging into a graphical environment as root. I do not think any distro supports log into a graphical environment as root.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen it actually is (or was?) possible to login as root user depending on the login manager and desktop environment. As specified in this answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/369012/how-to-run-a-complete-gui-as-root. But yeah, no sane person should do that.

Comment: its working properly but next day i turned on laptop and login but can not show screen. but asterisk user(other local user) display screen excepted Root.