# Any idea on how to enable root login through GUI on 17.10?

Tags: root, login-screen, 17.10

I was able to to do it on 17.04, but i guess the display manager has changed

I know it is not recommended. But it eases a lot of things for me.

Comment: This should work: https://askubuntu.com/a/369013/, just remember Ubuntu 17.10 uses `gdm3`.

Comment: I knew you would be the first to comment lol @pomsky . But no it didn't work... but thanks for pointing it out that it used gdm3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [link](https://economictheoryblog.com/2015/11/08/how-to-enable-gui-root-login-in-debian-8/) points it out for Debian, but instead of `daemon.conf` just edit `custom.conf`. Everything else is the same.

In a nutshell, first run

```
sudo vim /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Under `[security]` type `AllowRoot=true` so that it looks like

```
[security]
AllowRoot=true
```

Save and exit. Then run

```
sudo vim /etc/pam.d/gdm-password
```

Within this file you have comment out the line containing

```
auth required pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success
```

so that it looks like this

```
#auth required pam_succeed_if.so user != root quiet_success
```

Save the file and exit and reboot.

Comment: This answer worked for me.

Comment: @Michael Upvote it then :)

Comment: Too late, already did :) it seems some poor soul voted you down for some reason. Thanks for the answer anyways!

Comment: Also a) in /root/.profile, change "mesg n || true" to "tty -s && mesg n || true". b) pam restriction above is in /etc/pam.d/gdm-autologin and gdm-fingerprint if using autologin or fingerprint scanner. This is with 18.04.

Comment: @Jeevaka what u said applies to 17.10 as well, but has nothing to do with enabling GUI root login. The tty part you mentioned is to enable the root prompt once you assign password to root and the other part of for additional features like you mentioned. Nevertheless people visiting this post will find it helpful. Thanks 

Comment: Thank you so much. Finally it works for me after searching for all links over google