# What is the exact definition for "logging in"

Tags: login

Radu's answer is extremely informative here
[Why does the "who" command not show "root" as a logged in user?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376932/why-who-command-does-not-shows-root-as-a-logged-in-user)
However this makes me wonder "what is the exact definition for " logging in" in Linux?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a user account by providing a username, and a password is a part of logging in.  A user account is created only once. You are then logged in.  Next time you log in you will need to use  your username and password to prove that you are the same person.

Logging in allows you to use the system ,networks, and will allow you to use the applications installed.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: "creating a user account" and "logging in" are two different processes (regarding your 1st sentence).