# how to log in as root in Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: xubuntu, root

I am new to the world of linux and I've installed a Xubuntu 12.04 on my desktop computer. I am learning web development (Php, html, CSS, javaScript, JQuery etc...) so I need to establish an Apache server on my machine. With synaptic package manager I already installed some packages that seem to work so when I type localhost to my browser it gives an html site that says:

"It works! This is the default web page for this server. The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet."

I have read a few things on the internet on this topic, and now I know that I should be able to write my php in documents that are stored in filesystem/var/www/ but I cannot create documents in there - apparently because I am not logged in as root. Could somebody help me with that?

Also please note that I have very little (if any at all) knowledge of linux so please make it comprehesnible for such an uninitiated user as I am.

Comment: While it's possible to log in as root it is not recommended and `sudo` is the preferred way to run commands as root. See:[How to enable root login?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login)

Comment: Hey guys as I said I'm an amateur, I have no knowledge about terminal commands whatsoever. what I try to accomplish is to be permitted to save files into filesystem/var/www. Can somebody help me with that?

the sudo - i solution doesn't work neither does the one described here:How to enable root login?

please consider that I'm a newbie. I just installed my first ubuntu relase a couple hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

Type `sudo` in front of the commands you want to execute as root.
You cand easily create documents by going `sudo <your main text editor> <desired filename>`.

Also `sudo -i` of you want to keep elevated root rights until you command `exit`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I typed sudo -i to the terminal, then typed my password and it seemingly changed my status to root, but when i try to save a php document with gedit, it still errors with: "You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file". Can you help me with that?

Comment: Did you try doing `sudo gedit <filename>`? You need to start the editor from the terminal in which you've gained elevated rights.