# Can we login to the 'root' (Not as root user but in the 'root' user) user in ubuntu?

Tags: login, passwd

I want to login as user 'root' in bash shell, but do not know the password of it.
Here I am talking about the user which i have found in passwd as below:

> **sudo cat /etc/passwd
>
>   root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash**

So, my basic question is that can we able to login as 'root' user or not?
if yes and some know about it, let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. Log in to your administrator account and then run `sudo su root`. Enter your password and then you are logged in as root.

(Usually the root prompt looks similar to this: `root@computername:~#` (note the `#` instead of the `$`))

NOTE: be careful when you do that, everything you command is done immediately without asking for a password (just in case you didn't know)

Instead of logging in to the root account you might want to use `sudo` and your command (e.g. `sudo apt-get update`).

EDIT: "[...] The [root] password is set to a special value which doesn't match any possible key combination." - [fkraiem](https://askubuntu.com/users/256317/fkraiem)

Comment: "As far as I know there is no root password set." More accurately, the password is set to a special value which doesn't match any possible key combination. "No password" generally means you can login without a password.

Comment: Oh, thanks, good to know. May I quote you in my answer?

Comment: Sure. :) (Additional characters to reach the limit.)

Comment: Thanks :) Is the way I quoted you ok?

Comment: Yes, it's fine.

Comment: By the way, despite what its name implies, `/etc/passwd` does not contain password-related data. The passwords (in hashed form) are in `/etc/shadow` (you see that root's password looks different from that of a regular user).

Comment: Ah, I see. The root account has a '!' on my system in the password field which means that this user can not log in using a unix password (according to the manual page `shadow(5)`)

Answer (score 0):

It is worth to note you can run commands as `root` by putting a `sudo` in front of it as well. For example:

`sudo chown user:user filename`

Comment: I knew that sudo behave as root user. Even i would like to know how can i login as 'root' user. So, i have asked this. Thank you ('_').

Comment: Okie dokie, I only mention it because using `sudo` is safer than staying logged in as `root`