# How To login With Root in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: root

Hi Team Of Ubuntu I Want To ask You . How To login With Root In Ubuntu 14.10

Sorry My English Is Bad

Comment: You don't want to do this. See http://askubuntu.com/a/16179/57914 for a great explanation of why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable root login?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login), but I completely agree with Richard.

Answer (score 2):

Type `sudo su` in the terminal. This will open a root session. **Be very careful**, as you can do very bad things with this.

If you want to run a program in a GUI as root, type "gksudo".

However, [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login?rq=1) may be of use to you. It is *much* more dangerous than simply using sudo. If you want to do it, you can. (Command is `sudo passwd -u root [password]`)