# How to enable / disable root user account in ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, login, root

I'm new to Ubuntu OS, recently I'm installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my system. I'm trying to enable my root user by terminal using following commands :

```
sudo passwd root
```

and then :

```
sudo passwd -u root
```

It gives me a message :

```
passwd: password expiry information changed
```

But when I'm restarted my system it did not shows `ROOT` account for login. Is I made any mistakes.

I referred following link :
In this link they give the answer to enable root user, but it is not working in my case.
[How to enable root login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login)

Please any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

What if I want to install any software for all users, without using terminal and commands, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

For the most of Ubuntu usage, you do not actually need to enable the root user.
In case you want act as root in a terminal, just switch using:

```
sudo -i
```

and type the password.
To revert to your user, just type `exit`

Comment: I got that, but what if I want to install any software for all users. Is there any way to install using GUI of current user without using terminal and sud -i ?

Comment: Depends on the type of software you are installing.
Softwares installed from repository, via apt-get, are available for all the users.
For other softwares, there are many possibilities. 
I personally prefer to install them into /opt/ and add  the following line in the user's .bashrc

``export PATH=/opt/path_to_software_bin:$PATH``

and enable the new PATH with ``source .bashrc``
Other solution is to put a symbolic link to the executable  in system  /bin/ folder, but this solution is less flexible in case of software update.