# Why su didn't work?

Tags: command-line, permissions, root, su

I'm new to ubuntu .. i tried to use `su` command to enter as a root but didn't work but i tried to use `sudo -i`  , `su root` and `sudo -s` worked

I need to know why `su` didn't work ?

Comment: Because the user root is disabled by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: how can i make it enable ?

Comment: You give it a password, but it is not recommended since you can use sudo to accomplish what you would need as a root user.

Comment: One reason why you don't want it enabled is that it is the number one account that hackers use to break into systems with.  http://askubuntu.com/a/44419/647604

Answer (score 0):

By default, for security reasons, Ubuntu disables root login.

If, for some reason, `sudo` does not do what you want it to, or you would like to directly login as root on a TTY, open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo passwd root
```

This will prompt you for your password, then a new root password. As usual, the password will be hidden, without replacement characters. Please try and use `sudo` as much as possible and only use the above as a last resort, as this is not recommended.