# Admin user in Ubuntu 16.04, similar to OpenSUSE 42.x

Tags: administrator

I use openSUSE 42.x for my work, among other reasons the one I like most is its user management. I have one user on my machine say "**User1**" with "**pass1**". Whenever I need to run an application as **sudo** through terminal, I type sudo and it prompts for admin password which is different than "pass1".

One advantage is that I can share my machine without giving the admin password as both are different. I hope you understand what I mean if you have used openSUSE.

Now my question is "*how to replicate this behavior in Ubuntu 16.04?*". It looks like I have to make two different user accounts (one admin, one standard) if I want to share my Ubuntu machine with others.

At the moment I have one user account on **Ubuntu 16.04** which is an Admin. I would like to be prompted for password (different) if I run a command with "**sudo**", just like I do in the openSUSE.

Pardon my lack of knowledge in Ubuntu. Please, let me know if question isn't clear enough.

Regards,

Comment: Google mostly shows "how to make sudo work in suse like ubuntu does". Not the other way around. Most of us do not know suse here ;-) but what you are looking for is to enable root account (ie. set a password for "root"). I would advice against it and learn to use the Ubuntu way. FYI: you should not tell anyone any of your passwords anyways. That includes "Pass1" ;-)  Also: maybe the easiest to do would be to set auto login and nobody should need your password for logging in and anything else.

Comment: Regarding root see https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login