# always bybass password prompt

Tags: password

NOT ANSWERED -  I think Zanna gets th gist of it.
It seems most miss the point... the system is mine and my responsibility. I simply do not want to be prompted for a pasword as specified below... GETS MORE AND MORE FRUSTRATING. my email if someone wants to answer directly to me is zeteo1052@gmail.com
......................

I have not found the answer to this anywhere on line and I am getting really frustrated.
I will pay for support if it will get me the answer I've been looking for.
I am 68 years old and a retired computer desktop support technician. I have been using Ubuntu for over 2 years now and will not go back to Windows (the dark side) LOL
I want to be able to access files and folder, install packages, burn usb drives or dvd's etc. without always being prompted for a password.
I really understand the DANGER of it and always have a backup of my computers if need to restore it. I am not worried about losing anything. This is my computer and supposedly my OS and is my headache no matter what happens. I'm getting old and need to save all the time I can...  LOL
Is there any way you can help me? I know all about the visudo and tried all the procedures I could find but I am still being prompted for the password.
Thank for your time and consideration.

Comment: Sudo is baked very deeply in Ubuntu, so this seems like a square-peg-in-a-round-hole problem. Instead of haywiring Ubuntu, consider using Debian or another distro that has a different perspective on security. Lots of them out there. Remember, you're not a *customer*; you're not locked into Ubuntu. Use a distro that feels like an extension of yourself instead of a distro you want to fight.

Comment: This is quite easy, and it has been answered in quite a few other places online. So the question is: "how to set up Ubuntu gnome to automatically login a local user?"  I get a pretty good step by step explanation by googling the above phrase, but basically you need to modify a user account to: "login automatically." Go: >Settings>Users Select: "Your account" and turn on Automatic Login. You might edit your question and be more to the point, then someone could venture to answer that one for you. Cheers!

Comment: PS: Rooting your user account would be fabulous catastrophe, DON"T DO IT! 

You can 'sudo' and enter your password anytime you need to.    Good luck.

Comment: @ThompsonDawes It looks to me like OP is asking how to use `sudo` without a password (which is not the same as logging in as root, which is a very bad idea - setting up `sudo` to not require a password is a more mildly bad idea but it would be good if we could explain why, and how a backup might not help), not how to log in automatically. That would not allow them to do all the things they mentioned, I think.

Comment: The problem, as I see it, is that allowing sudo with no password still gives password checks in the software center and other GUI apps - it only applies in terminal. And I guess the OP asks how to get rid of those password prompts as well. In that case I guess one option is to have a very short local password.

Comment: You may find some useful stuff in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login)

Comment: ...like an unpaid Layer sir.