# why scp foo.txt root@remoteMaching: fails

Tags: 20.04, vmware

`scp foo.txt user1@192.168.23.130:.` can succeed, while `scp foo.txt root@192.168.23.130:.` always fail, after I input the correct root password as scp requires, it always say: `Permission denied, please try again`

Why is that?  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server version, with FinalShell3.8.3

---

another question which may have something common, which is also related with the root user:

Why ssh client always say access denied when I ssh a remote machine with root?  I tried with different ssh clients and the results are the same.

Comment: In Ubuntu, `root` account is disabled for good reasons. You don't need it. Login as normal user and run `sudo su -` to become `root`. However, if you still want to enable it, see the linked question:  [How to enable root login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because of `#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` (or similar) in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. Uncomment this line, change it to `PermitRootLogin yes` and reload `sshd`. Please note, that this is not recommended!

Comment: if `root login is prohibit` is given, it woulb be much better.