# ssh-copy-id returning permission denied

Tags: 16.04

When I try to use `ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 root@192.168.134.140`, it always returns `Permission denied, please try again`

I know that `ssh-copy-id` is a script in which `scp` and `ssh` is used. And `scp` to something like `root@192.168.134.140` will fail. It makes sense to me.

But, after I unlocked the root user following the answer in this post: [How to enable root login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login), still it fails. Why is that and how can fix that: All I want is to ssh as a root user to 192.168.134.140 without password.

Comment: Did you try with `sudo`? Else you will not have access into `root` homedir.

Comment: In order to use `ssh-copy-id` without an **existing** key on the server, you will need to authenticate via password - as well as enabling root login, that requires that the sshd configuration `PermitRootLogin` is set (at least temporarily) to allow password authentication for root. Did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

The link in your question points to enable Root login on your local machine. However, you might need to configure your `openssh-server` to allow Root logins.

---

But your primary issue is:

The file `/root/.ssh/id_ed25519` is only accesible by `root` and that is why you get a `Permission denied`.

You **could** use

```
sudo ssh-copy-id -i /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 root@192.168.134.140`
```

However, you should **not** do that.
You don't need to use your local `root` to connect to a remote `root` user.

Either:

- copy `/root/.ssh/id_ed25519` to your normal user.

  ```bsh
  sudo cp -t ~/.ssh/ /root/.ssh/id_ed25519* && sudo chown $USER: ~/.ssh/id_ed25519*
  ```
- or create a new key with `ssh-keygen`

And then use `ssh-copy-id` with the newly created or copied one (without `sudo`).

---

Anyways,

You should not enable and use `root` login via `ssh`.
Rather connect with a "normal" user and use `sudo` to elevate priviliges. You can also enable passwordless `sudo` for that user if you want that convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right permissions for the ssh files.

- **.ssh folder**: There should be read, write and execute privileges to the owner. So, we need to change the permission by `chmod 700 ~/.ssh`.
- **Public key**: we need to have read and write permissions for the owner and read permissions for other groups. So, we need to change the permission by `chmod 644 <your_public_key>`.
- **Private key**: we need to have read and write permissions for the owner and give no permissions to other groups. We need to change the permission by `chmod 600 <your_private_key>`.

Check if you have changed the `PasswordAuthentication no` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. If you have regenerated the ssh-keys, then we need to change the `PasswordAuthentication yes` in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. After enabling password authentication in the file, we just have to restart the ssh service by `sudo systemctl restart ssh`. Then try to copy the public keys. After copying the ssh keys, we can change `PasswordAuthentication no` and restart the service.

You should not enable root user login as it creates a major security issue. If you really want to enable it, then set `PermitRootLogin yes` in the same file.