# Enable Root Login in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: root

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is there no option to login as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6676/why-is-there-no-option-to-login-as-root)

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 version. I have enabled root through terminal. But there is no display for root-login in login window.