# Is there a way to have the login password different from the su password?

Tags: login, password, su

I have a friend that's running Debian and his computer login password is different from the superuser password. I was wondering if there's a way to do this in Ubuntu?

Comment: See [Why is there no option to login as root?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6676/why-is-there-no-option-to-login-as-root)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, they are already different, only the `root` account is disabled. That's really the difference. Ubuntu has a rather [strong stance](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) on this subject, and they insist `sudo` is the way to go, rather than having a separate `root` account. So they disable it.

If you really want to have a `root` account like Debian, it's quite easy:

```
sudo -i
sudo passwd root
```

and then set a password. This will be the password you use when you do `su`.

If you want to go crazy with it, you might be inclined to remove yourself from the `sudo` group with:

```
sudo deluser username sudo
```

Please make sure you understand the implications of these changes. Read the wiki page linked above.

Comment: happy to help!!

Comment: Even Debian is advising the use of sudo (see https://wiki.debian.org/Root). sudo have a long list of advantages over su (as given in the link).

Comment: Well, I haven't used Debian in a long time. I know FreeBSD is still using root.