# Error 13 Permission Denied

Tags: permissions

- Any reason I can't just drop a file into a directory ?

ie: `/var/lib/whatever`

I know it's a root access issue, but...

- Is this not an option due to the root limitation with Ubuntu?

I have a buddy who isn't a fan of Ubuntu because of this very reason & will only run Cent OS. Is there a way to prove him otherwise?

Comment: What? Your friend likes running around as root and dropping files in random directories? O.o

Comment: Why do you want to put something in /var/lib?

Comment: Among other things, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/16178/why-is-it-bad-to-login-as-root, http://askubuntu.com/q/6676/158442 and

Comment: Wait a minute, are you claiming that CentOS allows you to drop random files in /var/lib and Ubuntu doesn't, and that's why your friend doesn't like Ubuntu?

Comment: He's probably referring to an option to view the filesystem as root. You can do this with nautilus using `sudo nautilus`. I seem to remember doing that using icewm on antixos which is a debian based distro just like ubuntu. It's not that you can't, you'd just have to add the right package (file manager) or set the configuration yourself. As it's centos he's probably referring to using the KDE file manager which does allow this option. Sounds like a good social-engineering trick though!

Answer (score 6):

If the folder is owned by `root` user, and you're trying to drop the file with your user, it's normal behavior that Ubuntu doesn't allow you to do it.

## Options

- Give write permission for your user in the desired folder (`chmod 775 destination/folder`)
- Do the action you want via terminal with 'sudo' (`sudo mv /path/file /destination/folder`)

Comment: Thanks for the actual response.I'm not sure why this post garnered down votes. For those who down voted, I did a search & found post resembling error 13, but nothing was spot on for what I was asking.

Answer (score 2):

The layout of the file system is based on the [Filesystem Hierarchy System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) which designates certain directories as being available for users, and others available for the system, and so forth.

`/var/lib` is a space where the programs you have installed on your system can store their own information, such as system-wide settings, databases and so on.  It's not intended for users to put files into.

Comment: I'm running Folding @ Home. It's working fine, however it won't see my GPU. I found a post on the FAH Standford page regarding Linux & how to get it to pick up the GPU. The fix is to add a GPU text file to the /var/lib/fahclient directory.