# How to move VirtualBox VirtualMachines from root to specified user and where to move it?

Tags: software-installation, permissions, virtualbox, virtualization

I've installed VirtualBox being logged in to root and i forgot to switch accounts,
and I've installed few OS'es from DVD's.

Now I do not know how to mount ISO's and how to use it either because of permissions and many others... while I'm not logged in as root user.

So the question is how can i repair my situation and move VMs I've already installed
for root user only , and where to move it?
I'm able to open VB as not root user but i can see no VMs, as well I can't localize catalogue for VirtualBox as non root.

Please, help.

Comment: In a default Ubuntu [Root login is disabled](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6676/why-is-there-no-option-to-login-as-root) to avoid issues like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your username is `john` (replace with what you have), log in as root (doing that wasn't good anyway) and move the directory containing your VMs to `/home/john`. Then, assuming that your VirtualBox VMs directory is now located in `/home/john/VirtualBox` (again, change as required), execute this as `root`:

`chown -R john:john /home/john/VirtualBox`

Then, log in as your normal user (in this case `john`), start up VirtualBox and from the menu choose `Machine` => `Add...` for each machine.

You may need to adjust the VM settings afterwards, though. But this should do the trick.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, to locate where your machines are located under the `root` user, open VirtualBox, then `File` => `Preferences...` => `General` => `Default Machine Folder`.